# Why the GCD does not work?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock

Why follewing GCD does not work? All subthreads pause at `__ulock_wait`, but have not deadlock.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("test_gcd_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
            NSLog(@"---- gcd: %d", i);
        });
    });
    //NSLog(@"---------- async over: %d", i);  //Have this, OK.
}
NSLog(@"-------------------- cycle over");
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 2):

This can't work because the inner `dispath_sync()` uses the same queue it runs on. Its block must wait until the last item in the queue is executed. Since the current code is in the queue this is a deadlock, because the `dispatch_sync()` waits of the termination of its surrounding block.

On a concurrent queue you may have the same effect if you start more tasks than threads in the queue. Each loop iteration needs two threads. If at some point during execution all threads are blocked by an asynchronous task at the start of `dispatch_sync()` no synchronous task has the chance to start, and thus no asynchronous task has the chance to finish.

The loop in your code will create very quickly a huge amount of asynchronous tasks. They clog up the queue because of the startup overhead of every task. So only some few synchronous tasks have the chance to start and to let their asynchronous task to finish.

If to inserts a small delay (say 1ms for instance) into the outer loop, this clogging should be mitigated or even removed.

Comment: I don't think so.The DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT queue does not work as your said. I think this issue is related to thread quotas.

Comment: @fyxrhyry: I've extended my post for the case of multiple threads.